# Why does SIFR rendering this page in Chrome as a blank page?

Tags: sifr, cufon

In chrome - http://unitonenine.com/ loads for a few seconds that changes into a blank white page. This site was working fine up until a few months ago.

Upon inspection it just loads the 2 swf files. In FireFox it loads just fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I posted some information regarding the same bug that seems to be removed. So I poked around the javascript source for sifr r436 and discovered as was mentioned here:

http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=24243

That there was an issue with the prefetch function and indeed commenting the prefetch function out fixes the problem. I looked at the site linked above and this is not their solution. I have not been able to figure out how they resolved it, the prefetch function is unchanged on their site. So removing the prefetch would make this problem go away, however it is important to know that this will slow total page load time by putting off calling the flash file until after the rest of the page loads.